# Send an Email to new users added to an ACF User Field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I am trying to have an email send when a user is added to an ACF user field, I don't want existing users that are in the field already to be notified. Below are a few options I have tried, but am not having luck with. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Option 1:

```
add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_hook_email'); function my_acf_save_hook_email( $post_id ) { 
// // Get the list of user ids that are currently in the ACF field
$current_pds_project_managers = get_field('pds_project_manager');

// Get the list of user ids that were just added to the ACF field
$added_pds_project_managers = $_POST['pds_project_manager'];

// Get the list of user ids that are newly added, and not already in the ACF field
$newly_added_pds_project_managers = array_diff($added_pds_project_managers, $current_pds_project_managers);

// Send an email to each newly added user
foreach ($newly_added_pds_project_managers as $user) {
    $user_email = $user['user_email'];
    wp_mail( $user_email, 'You have been added to a project', 'You can now access the project from your dashboard.' );
}
}
```

Option 2: (this ends up sending 2 emails to the existing users in the field and one email to the new user, I then started with option one to see if I could only get the new users to no avail)

```
add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_hook_email', 5); function my_acf_save_hook_email( $post_id ) { 

// bail early if no pds_project_manager 
if( empty('pds_project_manager') ) { 
return; }

// Get the value of the ACF field 
$project_managers = get_field('pds_project_manager', ''); 
// Create an empty array to store the emails 
$emails_to_send = array(); 

// Loop through the project managers 
foreach ($project_managers as $project_manager) { 
// Get the user data 
$user_email = $project_manager['user_email'];
$user_id = $project_manager['ID'];
    
// Check if the user already exists in the array 
if (!in_array($user_id, $project_managers)) { 
// Add the user to the emails to send 
$emails_to_send[] = $user_email; } } 
// Send emails to the users 
foreach ($emails_to_send as $email_to_send) { 
// Send the email 
wp_mail($email_to_send, 'You Have Been Added To A Project', 'You have been added to a project. Please check the project page for more information.'); } }
```

Comment: In the second version, you are looping over `$project_managers`, to fill `$user_id` with the ID of the current project manager - and then you try to use in_array to check if the user was not contained in that array, that you just fetched it from in the first place ...? Besides that not making sense to begin with, you are also using in_array wrong there - `$project_managers` is not an array of plain user IDs, so trying to _find_ $user_id in there this way won't work to begin with.

Comment: If `$_POST['pds_project_manager']` gets you the IDs you need, as the comment in your first attempt indicates - well then why don't you use that now in your second attempt? Or is that not actually just the newly _added_ users?

Comment: the $project_mangers gets the ACF user field which is an array of user objects, so then I was pulling the IDs from there, not getting it twice.

Comment: When I was debugging this `$_POST['pds_project_manager']` wasn’t outputting anything, I am going to see if I can mess with it some more because if I can get that to work combing the two should work.